# Help understanding proof of greedy graph spanner algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

The following is taken [from here](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/fileadmin/inf/d1/teaching/summer19/algorithms/lecture_notes_spanners.pdf). I need help understanding a proof given in the link and quoted here (mostly).

Consider the following algorithm to build a subgraph H of a graph G:

[image]

Girth definition:
[image]

I fail to understand the following lemma

[image]

> It follows that the following condition ... is not satisfied.

Where did the requirement that
[image]

suddenly come from? Why does it contradict anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are simply saying that it is impossible for a cycle $C$ of length $2k$ or less to exist in $H$.

To see this assume that it does, and let $u,v$ be the last edge of $C$ that got added in the process. Notice that it is impossible for $u,v$ to have been added at this point, this completes the proof.

The reason why it is impossible for the edge $u,v$ to have been added is because the other edges of $C$ give us a path from $u$ to $v$ of length $2k-1$ or less. Meaning that the condition $d_H(u,v) > (2k-1)$ could not have been satisfied, and the algorithim could not have added the edge.

Comment: I only wasted 3 hours on this before asking :( This was so simple. I wish I had asked sooner

Comment: Glad to have been able to help ! If it helps I've wasted way more than $3$ hours on stuff like this.